# JavaScript onclick - incorrect interpretation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a problem when storing onclick event to html code of page.
Name of products on `tr` when table fills with rows should be shown like this:

```
<tr onclick="cart_pr('0K2FA-50030XX')">...</tr>
```

Only one article of all (named **"1000 fa"**) is showing wrongly like this:

```
<tr onclick="cart_pr('1000" fa')>...</tr>
```

Which is wrong, just look at " quote after 1000.

As a result, when clicking on article "1000 fa" I receive "Invalid unexpected token".
Function that fills that table works like this:

```
function FillArticles()
{
    //---------    Request to DB -----------//
    //---------    Parse json etc.

    for(i=0;i<json.length;i++)
    {
        //-----    Here goes loop to fill a table  ----//

        res.push("<tr onclick=cart_pr('"+obj.name+"')></tr>");

        //-----    I don't show more, cause only line above is important, so....
        //-----    below Closes the row with </tr>
        res.push("</tr>");
    }
    $("#mytable").html(res.join(''));
    //---------    In this line in debugger, res is absolutely OK
}
```

What should I do in this case? Help :))

Comment: Escape double and single quotes inside `obj.name` with a \

Comment: Don't add inline event handlers, especially when you're already working with jQuery!

Comment: use javascript unobtrusively. avoid using onclick attributes to bind events, instead use `.on()`

Comment: And fix those damn curly braces! Jeez, my eyes hurt

Comment: @jjj he'd still have to store the string as a data- attribute on the element, so that approach wouldn't save him any code.

Comment: Yeah, I was thinking before posting this here that better solution is just doing it by `.on()` and I will change my strategy etc., BUT I wanna know what is the issue with this one, why is this not working

Comment: i think *onclick="function()"*   but here missing double quotes *onclick=cart_pr('"+obj.name+"')*

Comment: @Blazemonger Why would he need a data attribute? The whole table should be created as elements instead of one big HTML string.

Comment: @JJJ hmm can you make an example,please, what does it mean "as elements"?? :) I know only `array.push()` and so.... or I really don't understand smth hahah

Comment: You should create the elements like this: `$('<tr>').on('click', function() { cart_pr( obj.name ); }).appendTo( '#mytable' );` and similarly create the <td> elements and append them to the <tr> elements.

Comment: @JJJ nice! But listen, if I have, for example 1000 rows to store, i've heard that `append` is slow and they said me to use `push` instead... probably `appendTo` is different to `append`. But I like your code :) Also, I can do `.on()` after `join()`, what do you think?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed to add quotes `&#39;` instead of `'`

```
res.push("<tr onclick='cart_pr(&#39;"+obj.name+"&#39;);'></tr>
```

But this is surely not the best method to make tables with clickable rows, specially when using functions that have multiple arguments.

It's better to use `.on()` with JQuery instead of this approach.